# Looping multiple Excel sheets in read_excel into a concatenated dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a file that will have a tab for each "fund" that is referenced on its own separate tab. I want to read all of these into a single concatenated dataframe. I used the below to do it in a very manual way, but the number of worksheets could change.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(threeDaysFile)
fund0000 = pd.read_excel(xls, 0)
fund0001 = pd.read_excel(xls, 1)
fund0002 = pd.read_excel(xls, 2)
fund0003 = pd.read_excel(xls, 3)
fund0004 = pd.read_excel(xls, 4)
all_funds = pd.concat([fund0000, fund0001, 
fund0002, fund0003, fund0004])
```

Is there an efficient way to write this into a context sensitive loop that will just bring in all worksheets on the current file and concatenate them to a master file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `xls.sheet_names`

```
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname=x) for x in xls.sheet_names])
```

If you need which sheet the data come from

```
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname=x) for x in xls.sheet_names],keys=xls.sheet_names)
```